# Writing 3rd party plugins for closed-source Netbeans Platform Application

Tags: plugins, rcp, netbeans-plugins

I have created a Netbeans Platform Application and deployed it (created installer / zip bundle etc.). I have also made provision for extension points by creating Interface modules in the application (is this the correct way?).

Now my question is, how do I write modules to extend this application, without having to depend on the source of the application. For example, I want to write a module that implements one of the interfaces. How do I create a new module project that does this, and how do I get the Platform Application to include / find this new module.

I am trying to write an RCP application using the Netbeans Platform Application architecture. I want to be able to make it extendible (via interfaces) WITHOUT having to expose the source to 3rd party developers. I do intend to publish the source, but from a design perspective I want it to be functional enough that people don't need to have the source to write plugins for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it. You can do it with the normal Java service discovery methods. Add a file under META-INF/services/ with the same name as the interface you are implementing, and in the file put the name of the class. Both have to be the FULLY QUALIFIED name of the class.